# How To Ask For User Consent In Android 11

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, android-11

It works perfectly fine for android 10 but does not work in android 11 after some research I found out that we must ask for user consent, so I have gone through some video and I didn't understand how to so can anyone help me out here!

```
           File file = new File(childItem.getPath());

                file.delete();
                if (file.exists()) {
                    try {
                        file.getCanonicalFile().delete();
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            deleteFile(file.getName());
                        }
                    } catch (IOException unused) {
                        unused.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Consent to do what?

Comment: @Julia To delete the file, so basically it's necessary in android 11 to ask users before deleting a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Andorid11; you need user-interaction for modify or delete any files from external storage. You need to use `createDeleteRequest` for deletion of file.
You can follow this steps:

```
if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
  List<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();
  
  // Your for loop starts here, if you want to delete multiple files..
  
// for(File childItem : yourFileList){

      long mediaID = getFilePathToMediaID(childItem.getPath(), MainActivity.this);
      Uri Uri_one = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri("external"), mediaID);
      uris.add(Uri_one);
     // } /*for ends here */
        
             requestDeletePermission(MainActivity.this, uris);
}
```

now create delete request like this;

```
 private static final int REQUEST_PERM_DELETE = 444;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    private void requestDeletePermission(Context context, List<Uri> uri_one) {
        PendingIntent pi = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(context.getContentResolver(), uri_one);
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(pi.getIntentSender(), REQUEST_PERM_DELETE, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

now handle result in your `onActivityResult` ;

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_PERM_DELETE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Deleted successfully! Refreshing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to delete!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

        }
    }

 public static long getFilePathToMediaID(String songPath, Context context) {
        long id = 0;
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
        String[] selectionArgs = {songPath};
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID};
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

        Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, projection, selection + "=?", selectionArgs, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                id = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(idIndex));
            }
        }

        return id;
    }
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply, But The Dialog Box is not Showing For Some Reasons, and it's not deleting

Comment: @AyanShaikh createDeleteRequest will auto display dialog. there may some issue from your side while calling this. Otherwise this is working.

Comment: I Debugged the code and the code went till here             startIntentSenderForResult(pi.getIntentSender(), REQUEST_PERM_DELETE, null, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: mediaID should be numeric only. Also check your logs with android11.

Comment: It worked, but it showed the dialog box after reopening the app, do you know the issue?

Comment: its not like that. It works perfectly on first time also. You need to check your code for this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Step 1

```
private void get_files_to_delete() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            List<Uri> uri_list = new ArrayList<>();

//            File my_folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+"Your folder");

            File my_single_file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+"Your folder"+"/"+"example.mp3");

//            File[] list_fil = my_folder.listFiles();

       // Your for loop starts here, if you want to delete multiple files..

//            for (File childItem : list_fil) {
            
                if (my_single_file.exists()) {
                    Uri Uri_one = getFilePathToMediaID(my_single_file.getPath(), MainActivity.this);
                    uri_list.add(Uri_one);
                }
                
//            }  /*for ends here */


            requestDeletePermission(MainActivity.this, uri_list);
        }
    }
```

Step 2

```
private Uri getFilePathToMediaID(String path, Context context) {
        
        Uri contentUri = null;
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
        String[] selectionArgs = {path};
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID};
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

        Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, projection, selection + "=?", selectionArgs, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                long id = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(idIndex));
                contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
            }
        }
        
        return contentUri;

    }
```

Step 3

```
private static final int REQUEST_PERM_DELETE = 444;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    private void requestDeletePermission(Context context, List<Uri> uri_list) {
        try {
            PendingIntent editPendingIntent = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(context.getContentResolver(), uri_list);
            startIntentSenderForResult(editPendingIntent.getIntentSender(), REQUEST_PERM_DELETE, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

finally, you can replace 'MediaStore.Audio' to 'MediaStore.Video'

I hope this helps you.